# How to enable download progress bar in a web browser during file download in PHP script?

Tags: php, http, download, http-headers

I have the following PHP script that outputs a file for download to an end-user:

```
session_write_close();
ob_end_clean();
set_time_limit(0);

if($file = fopen($path, 'rb'))
{
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header("Content-length: ".(string)(filesize($path)));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($path)."\"");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Connection: close");

    fpassthru($file);
    fclose($file);
}
```

The user can download the file just fine, but when a large file is being downloaded the web browser doesn't show a progress bar with the percentage of the file remaining to download. It only displays the number of MB currently downloaded.

So I'm curious, what shall I change in the header to enable this download progress?

PS. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is gzip and tied to not knowing actual content length... maybe add this header?

```
header("accept-encoding: gzip;q=0,deflate;q=0");
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't change it. I also tried just `Accept-encoding: gzip; deflate;`.

Comment: Do you think its gzip related?  Looking at the request can you see if compression is being used?  Could try turning it off on the web server just to test.  What is the web server in question?

Comment: The server is `Apache/Linux 3.12.35.1418868052`. How do I find out if it's using gzip? Also what's the way to dump the headers via php?

Comment: Apache's [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html).  Disable with `SetEnv` call usually.  Or suppose comment out module and restart.  Are you asking about PHP's `headers_list()` - I'd suggest using firebug/fiddler/wireshark or the like to get better insight.